# BOOTSTRAP I'm trying align divs with bootstrap, but doesn't work

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to align divs with bootstrap, but it doesn't work.
I don't want to do it by table I have tried with the table tag, but I want to do it by using divs and bootstrap.

I'm not an expert with bootstrap as you can see, but I'm trying.
Can anyone help me?

My screen:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
    <div class="d-flex flex-column">
        <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-around">
            <div class="d-flex flex-row">
                Código da filial:
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="CTD_ITEM">
            </div>
            <div class="d-flex flex-row">
                Nome:
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="CTD_DESC01">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-around">
            <div class="d-flex flex-row">
                Estado:
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="CTD_DESC04">
            </div>
            <div class="d-flex flex-row">
                Sigla:
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="CTD_DESC02">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use Grid System of Bootstrap this is a great feature of Bootstrap
and Here is example of your divs:

```html
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-4">
                        Código da filial:
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-8">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="CTD_ITEM">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-4">
                        Nome:
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-8">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="CTD_DESC01">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row mt-2">
            <div class="col-6">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-4">
                        Estado:
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-8">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="CTD_ITEM">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-4">
                        Sigla:
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-8">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="CTD_DESC01">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.14.7/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

You can duplication big div under container div to add more fields
Refernce of Grid System: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/grid/

Comment: ty so much... i'll study about that... help me a lot, <3